# elasticsearch query string format

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using

```
SearchBuilder.searchSource.query(query_string).buildAsBytes()
```

to perform the query string on elasticsearch servers.

The problem is that I dont know what is the correct format of query string. For instance, I want to find all documents with `country` field to be `US`, I can use the restful api of

```
http://my.elastic.search.server/foo/dummy/_search?q=country:US
```

to get what I need. But in terms of java api, I tried `country:US`, `q=country:US`, and `{\"country\":\"US\"}`, but each time I got back `SearchPhaseExecutionException`.

ElasticSearch's documentation does not shed any lights on what could be the format of query string in this case, and I have exhausted Google results related to this topic. Can someone help me on this? Thanks!

Comment: What does the `SearchPhaseExecutionException` say?

Comment: Do you want to create json via java or do you want to use the Java API?

Comment: So the 'more contrived JSON' works and tje recommemded "country:US" doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. seems like I need to pass in a more contrived json string

{
  "query_string" : {
         "default_field": "anotherFoo",
         "query": "this AND that OR there"
  }
}

It is useful in that I can pass in pure Lucene-style query against elasticsearch.

Answer (score 4):

Based upon your REST query the equivalent according to the [Search Java API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/java-api/search.html) would be:

```
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("foo")
    .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
    .setQuery(termQuery("country", "US"))
    .execute()
    .actionGet();
```

You could also use a pure query string as in your REST example:

```
    .setQuery(queryString("country:US"))
```

The best reference is the Javadoc available in the [Maven repository](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch).

Comment: what is the source for **termQuery()** ?

Answer (score 2):

I've written an overview on this topic recently:

http://karussell.wordpress.com/2012/01/19/birds-eye-view-on-elasticsearch-its-query-dsl/

Answer (score 1):

Its an old question but as I struggled quite a bit with similar query , I thought I would add my two cents.
 First of all I could not find

```
SearchBuilder.searchSource.query(query_string).buildAsBytes()
```

As mentioned in the original question any more in ES java API.

My request body looked like

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "file",
      "query": "Java"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "file": {

      }
    }
  }
}
```

I found this can be done in following two ways

```
    String queryString = "{" 
            + "\"query_string\": " 
                + "{"
                    + "\"default_field\":"
                + " \"file\","
                        + " \"query\": \"Email OR @gmail.com @yahoo.com\""
                        + "}"
                        + "}";
```

> **First Approach**

```
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();        
    searchSourceBuilder.query(queryString); //or searchSourceBuilder.query(queryString).buildAsBytes();

    SearchRequestBuilder searchRequestBuilder = new SearchRequestBuilder( ESConnectionFactory.INSTANCE.getClient()) ;
    searchRequestBuilder.internalBuilder(searchSourceBuilder).setIndices("resume")
    .setTypes("docs").addHighlightedField("file");
```

> **Second Approach**

```
SearchRequestBuilder searchRequestBuilder = client.prepareSearch()
                .setIndices("resume")
                .setTypes("docs").setQuery(queryString).addHighlightedField("file");
```

And then standard

```
SearchResponse response = searchRequestBuilder.execute().actionGet();
```

Keys things to note

1. **Do not add "query" in the queryString**
2. **Do not add highlighted fields in query string. Use addHighlightedField**

Answer (score 1):

I feel this should work.

```
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("pattern").field("field to search");
SearchRequestBuilder sreq = client.prepareSearch("INDEX").setTypes("TYPE").setQuery(qb);
SearchResponse response = sreq
                .setFrom("From page")
                .setSize("size")
                .execute().actionGet();
```